# How to find a pah to file in a test project

Tags: unit-testing, testing, reflection

I have a test project in my C# solution in Visual Studio.

In the same project is a .config file?

Is there any way how to get path to this file in runtime?

Comment: Is it question "In the same project is a .config file?" or you have forgotten "?" at the end of this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: You can also speak direct to some user if you think he or she can solve your question with "@MikroDel" for example - at the start of the comment. So you ask question and than post comment where you ask direct some person. This comment should be delete after it =)